# Why can not I print an element of an array right after assigning it in C in this code?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);
        printf("You entered: %d\n", a[i]);
    }

}
```

I wonder why I can't print the number this way? (Right after assigning it)

The output is:

**Enter: 5

6

You entered: 5

Enter: 3

You entered: 6

Enter: 8

You entered: 3

Enter: 9

You entered: 8

Enter: 1

You entered: 9**

and i expect it to be:

**Enter: 5

You entered: 5

Enter: 6

You entered: 6**

and so on

Comment: Please share more information. What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What else have you tried?

Comment: hey i've added the expected output. please check it out

Comment: @XueQing Do you have the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should erase "\n" in scanf function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        printf("You entered: %d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

Enter: 1
You entered: 1
Enter: 2
You entered: 2
Enter: 3
You entered: 3
Enter: 4
You entered: 4
Enter: 5
You entered: 5
```

Comment: everything looks fine on my side but the output is different

Comment: @Maxsym Kosov but why is it so?

Comment: Why do you need "\n" in scanf function?
If you are gonna input value, you should type "enter" so that's not needed.
And we can't add any other symbols in scanf function. This is basic syntax in programming.

Comment: I thought it would make a new line